# Bean injection failing in Library

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I created one library, in which i created some beans. Below is the file where i am creating some beans:

```
@Configuration
public class StorageBindings {

  @Value("${storageAccountName}")
  private String storageAccountName;

  @Value("${storageAccountKey}")
  private String storageAccountKey;


  @Bean(name = "cloudBlobClient")
  public CloudBlobClient getCloudBlobClientUsingCredentials() throws URISyntaxException {
     return new CloudBlobClient();
  }


  @Bean(name = "storageCredentialsToken")

  public StorageCredentialsToken getStorageCredentialsToken() throws IOException {
     return new StorageCredentialsToken();
  }

  @Bean(name = "msiTokenGenerator")
  public MSITokenGenerator getMSITokenGenerator() {
    return new MSITokenGenerator();
  }
}
```

Then i created the class, which i use as entry point to do further operations

```
public class StorageClient {

  @Autowired
  private CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;

  @Autowired
  private MSITokenGenerator msiTokenGenerator;

  @Value("${storageAccountName}")
  private String storageAccountName;

  @Value("${storageAccountKey}")
  private String storageAccountKey;
}
```

I created the jar with above files and include it in our main project, where i created the bean of StorageClient as below:

```
@Bean(name = {"storageClient"})
    public StorageClient getStorageClient() {
        LOG.debug("I am inside storage class");
        StorageClient ac = null;
        try {
            ac = new StorageClient();
            return ac;
    }
```

But after execution i found that no injection in StorageClient instance ac for below variables and not even environment property getting reflected and all of them are null:

```
   //beans NOT Injecting 
   ac.cloudBlobClient=null;
   ac.msiTokenGenerator=null;

//env variables
   ac.storageAccountName=null;
   ac.storageAccountKey=null;
```

Am i missing something, as i am getting null. Sequence of instantiation of beans are ok. I checked. So first beans of StorageBindings are getting created.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
ac = new StorageClient();
```

you lose the context of spring, because you are creating a new instance out of that context. The beans inside `CloudBlobClient`,`MSITokenGenerator` and variables `storageAccountName`,`storageAccountKey`, they don't get injected.

You can annotate `StorageClient` with `@Component`.

So since you pack it as jar, in your main project you have to make sure that the `@ComponentScan` includes the path where `StorageClient` is.

Then you can do:

```
@Autowired
private StorageClient storageClient;
```

in your main project.

Comment: One more doubt, I have bean MSITokenGenerator , which is created based on some condition. Now when i am autowiring MSITokenGenerator in other class, and if MSITokenGenerator bean is not created, i am getting some error. So is some kind of conditional autowiring is possible, i.e. just to autowire if bean exist.

Comment: You can do `@Autowired(required=false)` , and if the bean `MSITokenGenerator` not exists will be null, but there will be no exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating object inside `@Bean` annotated method autowiring doesn't inject beans there - you simply are creating it by yourself.
So you have to `@Autowire` it ie on fields in your `Configuration` class and set with setter/constructor.
Ie:

```
@Autowired
private CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;

@Autowired
private MSITokenGenerator msiTokenGenerator;

@Bean(name = {"storageClient"})
public StorageClient getStorageClient() {
       LOG.debug("I am inside storage class");
       StorageClient ac = null;
       try {
              ac = new StorageClient();
              ac.setCloudBlobClient(cloudBlobClient);
              ac.setMsiTokenGenerator(msiTokenGenerator);
              return ac;
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried  [@]Autowired
    private CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;

    [@]Autowired
    private MSITokenGenerator msiTokenGenerator; in main class, but there too, i am getting cloudBlobClient=null and msiTokenGenerator=null. Why these are comming as null

Comment: What do you mean by main class? It should be in the Configuration class as:  @Bean(name = {"storageClient"})